# Approximating the Fourier transform with DFT/FFT

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

Suppose I have a continuous function $f(x)$, $x\in[-L/2,L/2]$.  Its $L-$periodic Fourier coefficients are given by

$$
\hat{f}[k]=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}f(x)\exp(-2\pi ikx/L)dx
$$  If I apply the simplest imaginable left-hand Riemann sum to the above integral - say let

$$
x_j=-\frac{L}{2}+j\delta,\quad \delta=\frac{L}{N},\quad j=0,\ldots,N-1
$$ and then

$$
\begin{align}
\hat{f}[k]\approx\frac{\delta}{L}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}f(x_j)\exp(-2\pi ikx_j/L)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}f(x_j)\exp(ik\pi)\exp(-2\pi ijk/N)
\end{align}
$$ where the $\exp(ik\pi)$ comes from

$$
-2\pi ikx_j/L=-\frac{2\pi ik}{L}(-L/2+jL/N)=ik\pi-\frac{2\pi ijk}{N}
$$ So, it appears as though I have the following: if I let $f_s[j]=f(x_j)$ be the discrete list of samples, then

$$
\hat{f}[k]=e^{ik\pi}\hat{f}_s[k]
$$where $\hat{f}_s[k]$ is the *discrete* Fourier transform of $f_s$ (extended periodically as appropriate).

My question is the following: I really don't think that the $e^{ik\pi}$ factor, which will result in $(-1)^k$, should be there!  Where has my tired brain mislead me (or has it...)?

Comment: Periodic shifting in the discrete time domain by N/2 results in the modulation in the frequency domain.

Comment: Or use $x_j=jδ$ for $j=-N/2, ..., N/2-1$. The usual FFT has zero as the left point in the space and frequency dimensions. The Fourier coefficients then go from $0$ to the highest frequency $f_s/2$ and then wrap around to $-f_s/2$ to $0$ in the second half.